# Find correlation coefficient of $f(x,y)=2$ for $0<x \leq y<1$

Tags: probability

> Find the correlation coefficient for the random variables $X$ and $Y$ having joint density $f(x,y)=2$ for $0 < x \leq y<1$.

Seem like a simple problem but I'm stuck.

Since $\mbox{Corr}(X,Y) = \frac{\mbox{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\mbox{Var}(X)}\sqrt{\mbox{Var}(Y)}}$, I figure I start with $\mbox{Var}(X)$ and $\mbox{Var}(Y)$.

> $E(X) = \int_0^1 \int_0^y 2xdxdy = \int_0^1y^2dy = \frac{1}{3}$
>
> $E(X^2) = \int_0^1 \int_0^y 2x^2dxdy = \int_0^1\frac{2}{3}y^3dy = \frac{1}{6}$
>
> $\mbox{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{9} = \frac{1}{18}$
>
> $E(Y) = \int_0^1 \int_x^1 2ydydx = \int_0^1 1-x^2 dx = \frac{2}{3}$
>
> $E(Y^2) = \int_0^1 \int_x^1 2y^2dydx = \frac{2}{3}\int_0^1 1-x^3dx = \frac{1}{2}$
>
> $\mbox{Var}(Y) = E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{4}{9} = \frac{1}{18}$
>
> $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mbox{Var}(X)}\sqrt{\mbox{Var}(Y)}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{18}} = 18$

It seems alright up to this point.

> $\mbox{Cov}(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$
>
> $E(XY) = \int_0^1 \int_0^y 2xy dxdy = \int_0^1 y^3 dy = \frac{1}{4}$
>
> $\mbox{Cov}(X,Y) = \frac{1}{4} - (\frac{1}{18})^2$

And this is where I'm stuck.

> $\mbox{Corr}(X,Y) = (\frac{1}{4} - (\frac{1}{18})^2) \times 18 = \frac{18}{4} - \frac{1}{18} > 1$

Wolfram says my calculation is correct, so this must be a concept problem.
The $0 < x \leq y<1$ is really throwing me off but Devore doesn't really provide a clear explanation.

Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integrals look right. Note that $E(X)E(Y)=\frac{2}{9}$, so the covariance calculation is not right.

The covariance is $\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2}{9}=\frac{1}{36}$.

Comment: oh god. that was embarrassing. now imma slap myself and go join the fifth graders.

Comment: As inevitable as typos. And computers/calculators don't necessarily help. Keying and programming slips are also inevitable.

Comment: Actually, I was having trouble finding a mistake, but then noticed that the written down value for $E(XY)$ was **geometrically** highly implausible if one looks at the triangle. After that it was easy to spot the problem.

Comment: It reminds me that Polya's "have you seen a similar problem" can be applied in reverse to check answers.